# How to prove $ \left(\sum\limits_{cyc}{xy}\right)^2 \ge3xyz(x+y+z)$ with $x,y,z$ being positive real numbers

Tags: inequality

I have tried to improve the inequality by AM-GM. Here is what I have done:
Since
$$\sum_{cyc}{xy}\ge3\sqrt[3]{x^2y^2z^2}$$
$$\Rightarrow \left(\sum_{cyc}{xy}\right)^2 \ge3xyz\sqrt[3]{xyz}$$  That means we got to prove$\sqrt[3]{xyz} \ge x+y+z$.
However that is false in the case $x=1$,$y=2$,$z=3$.
Any help?

Comment: Is there something given about the numbers $x,y,z$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by "$cyc$"?

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas I think it is supposed to mean cyclic.

Comment: Yes. cyc means cyclic

Answer (score 4):

Simplify the inequality to 
$$x^2y^2+y^2z^2+x^2z^2\ge xyz(x+y+z)$$
If some of $x,y,z$ equals $0$, then the inequality is obvious.

So assume $xyz\neq 0$ and divide by $x^2y^2z^2>0$ both sides to get
$$\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2}\ge \frac{1}{yz}+\frac{1}{xz}+\frac{1}{xy}$$
This is true by the power of Cauchy Schwarz  $$\frac{1}{y}\cdot\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z}\cdot\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x}\cdot\frac{1}{y}\leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{x^2}}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}}$$

Comment: The last inequality you were trying to prove is the classical $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge ab+bc+ca$ in the form of $(a,b,c)=(1/x,1/y,1/z)$. There are many ways to prove it. E.g., it's equivalent to $\frac{1}{2}\left((a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\right)\ge 0$, which is true; or by the [Rearrangement Inequality](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Rearrangement_Inequality); or direct [Muirhead's Inequality](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Muirhead%27s_Inequality) (which is AM-GM in disguise).

Comment: @user236182 I know, just for completeness I showed it in one of all the possible ways.

Answer (score 1):

By the [Rearrangement Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality),
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac1x+\frac1y+\frac1z\right)^2
&=\frac1{x^2}+\frac1{y^2}+\frac1{z^2}+2\left(\frac1{xy}+\frac1{yz}+\frac1{zx}\right)\\
&\ge\frac1{xy}+\frac1{yz}+\frac1{zx}+2\left(\frac1{xy}+\frac1{yz}+\frac1{zx}\right)\\
&=3\left(\frac1{xy}+\frac1{yz}+\frac1{zx}\right)\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Multiply both sides of $(1)$ by $(xyz)^2$ to get
$$
(xy+yz+zx)^2\ge3xyz(x+y+z)\tag{2}
$$